# Using static_cast over compound operators

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm a beginner at C++ programming ...I was practicing and I encountered this problem...Here I'm trying to use static_cast over a compound operator...I'm actually trying to divide two integers and get the answer as double...This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int g {0}, h {0};
    cout << "Enter g and h: " << endl;
    cin >> g >> h;
    static_cast<double>(g) /= (h);
    cout << "g: " << g << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

now I know I can change int to double...or do something like this:

```
i = g/h;
cout << static_cast<double>(i) << endl;
```

but let's make this a challenge...what if we actually need to enter integers (not doubles)?

And this is the error I get:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Example: Changing data type by casting

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int total {0};
    int num1 {0}, num2 {0}, num3{0};
    const int count {3};

    cout << "Enter 3 integers: ";
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

    total = num1 + num2 + num3;
    double average {0.0};
    //This is where it confuses almost everyone. Imagine total is equal to 50, so average is equal to 16.66.
    //But the problem is that total is an integer so you will only get 16 as answer.
    //The solution is to convert it by casting.
    average = static_cast<double>(total) / count;
    //average = (double)total/count;      //Old-Style code

    cout << "The 3 numbers are: " << num1 << ", " << num2 << ", " << num3 << endl;
    cout << "The sum of the numbers are: " << total << endl;
    cout << "The average of the numbers is: " << average << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here. Are you attempting to convert `g` from an integer variable into a double variable?

Comment: Yes..that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: That's not possible. `g` is declared an `int`. It will always be an `int`.

Comment: You can't change the type of a variable after you declare it.

Comment: I'm not sure but I have seen examples where they change the data type by casting...let me actually post it in my question by editing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the function of `static_cast`.

`static_cast` will (if possible) convert a value to another type, and give you a resulting rvalue of the new type<sup>1</sup>. An [rvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) is not something you can assign to<sup>2</sup> (unlike an lvalue, which is what you're seeing in your error message).

In C++ a variable's type is given once and only once during the declaration. For that variable's entire lifetime it'll be of the type it was declared (Note this is different from weaker typed languages like Python or JavaScript).

---

In reply to your example, note that **no variables are changing their types.**

```
average = static_cast<double>(total) / count;
```

`average` was declared as a `double`, and it remains a `double`. The magic here is that you're casting `total` to `double`. So `static_cast<double>(total)` gives you a `double` with the equivalent value as the integer `total` (but this is no longer `total`! It's now a temporary unnamed `double`). You then divide that unnamed `double` by `count`, and assign the result to `average`.

---

<sup>1. Except in the case where the type to convert to is a reference type. (thanks Brian!)</sup>
<sup>2. For native types. "Any class type rvalue can be assigned to unless you explicitly forbid it." (Thanks Nathan!)</sup>

Comment: *An rvalue is not something you can assign to* This is only true for built in types.  Any class type rvalue can be assigned to unless you explicitly forbid it.

Comment: Note that `static_cast` can yield an lvalue if the type to convert to is a reference type.

Comment: Yeah...I guess you're right...maybe the only solution is to change int to double or float...

Comment: @David I've edited to try to address your example. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok..thank you everyone and thank you scohe001...Wish you all best of luck :)

Comment: You might want to mention that `rvalue` means value on the "right hand side" (of an assignment), and `lvalue` means value on the "left hand side" (of an assignment).  (Ie, the R and L means "left" and "right").  But that name is legacy, so it is just a way to remember which is which.